# bash download the first matching regex on download page

Tags: regex, bash, github, download, match

I want to get the newest (first) download link matching a regex.

```
URL=https://github.com/sharkdp/bat/releases/   # Need to look at /releases/ even though the downloads are under /releases/download/$REL/$BAT
content=$(wget $URL -q -O -)
# Parse $content for string starting 'https://' and ending "_amd64.deb"
# At the moment, that will be: href="/sharkdp/bat/releases/download/v0.18.3/bat_0.18.3_amd64.deb"
# wget -O to specify the name of the file into which wget dumps the page contents, and then - to get the dump onto standard output. -q (quiet) turns off wget output.
```

Then I need to somehow grep / match strings that starts `https://` and ends `_amd64`. Then I need to just pick the first one in that list.
How do I grep / match / pick first item in this way?

Once I have that, it's then easy for me to download the latest version on the page, with `wget -P /tmp/ $DL`

Comment: What about `wget -S --spider https://github.com/sharkdp/bat/releases/latest 2>&1 | grep '  Location:' | awk -F 'v' '{print $NF}`?

Comment: That very nicely returns the latest version number `0.18.3`, but it doesn't find the latest `href` link for the latest downloadable file (that ends `_amd64.deb`. Constructing a link and then testing it is a bit unreliable, because they might change their naming conventions for the full path, right? I like what you are doing here, but can it help to get to the objective of: return the full link of the latest valid download file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Bash, you can use

```sh
rx='href="(/sharkdp/[^"]*_amd64\.deb)"'
if [[ "$content" =~ $rx ]]; then 
    echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}";
else
    echo "No match";
fi
# => /sharkdp/bat/releases/download/v0.18.3/bat-musl_0.18.3_amd64.deb
```

The `href="(/sharkdp/[^"]*_amd64\.deb)"` regex matches `href="`, then captures into Group 1 (`${BASH_REMATCH[1]}`) `/shardp/` + zero or more chars other than `"` + `_amd64.deb` and then just matches `"`.

With GNU `grep`, you can use

```sh
> link=$(grep -oP 'href="\K/sharkdp/[^"]*_amd64\.deb' <<< "$content" | head -1)
> echo "$link"
# => /sharkdp/bat/releases/download/v0.18.3/bat-musl_0.18.3_amd64.deb
```

Here,

- `href="\K/sharkdp/[^"]*_amd64\.deb` - matches `href="`, then drops this text from the match, then matches `/sharkdp/` + any zero or more chars other than `"` and then `_amd_64.deb`
- `head -1` - only keeps the first match.

Comment: Works perfectly, and a nice learning example for me on the Perl \K option and a few other things, thanks. 